# Throwing undefined error for itune object

Tags: javascript, plugins

The following code is throwing undefined error.

```
try {
    var iTunesApp = new ActiveXObject("itunes.application");
}
catch (err) {
    alert(err.Message);
}
```

Comment: So maybe the itunes plugin is missing?

Comment: No i have installed it, and verified in "Manage add on" section, It is there!, Please help me

Comment: try clearing ur cache and restarting ur browser.